# How to change my mouse wheel scroll rate?

Tags: xorg, mouse, mouse-scroll, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'm using Chrome, and the scroll rate is like 3 lines, and it's painfully slow. My finger gets tired really quickly on long pages. *System → Preferences → Mouse* lacks any scroll wheel configuration options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase mouse wheel scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed)

Answer (score 63):

The fix for me for this (I had it for months) was pretty surreal and like most folks I didn't believe it until I did it:

Some MS mice have a scrollwheel bug.

> **Try unplugging the USB cable / dongle then plug back in.**

Also, I noticed that if you have the dongle plugged in to the computer and the mouse has an on-off mechanism then you can just turn the mouse off and back on. That resets the data link between the mouse and dongle.

:)

Comment: Fixed it for me.  My scroll rate was way too fast, not too slow, but same solution.  I have a KVM switch to go between a Ubuntu machine and Windows 7.  The problem returns every time I KVM back to the Ubuntu.  Give the mouse USB doodad few seconds of freedom, and the problem is gone.

Comment: I can't believe it. This fixes it for me as well.

Comment: Fixed MS Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000, FCC ID: c3k1452 model 1452

Comment: +1 I was skeptic too, but it works. When in doubt with MS, reboot.

Comment: In my case, just turning on and off my mouse worked.

Comment: Worked for me with a Logitech M705 Marathon Mouse.

Comment: Gosh, thank you!  (New Wireless MS Natural Keyboard & Mouse)

Comment: This answer don't fit with general situation

Comment: Thus your downvote.  The many up-voters might diagreee but that's fine.  Everyone gets one vote !

Comment: works for Microsoft Scuplt economical mouse. Would be nice to know if something specific causes this and if the reconnect can be automated somehow so i don't have to reach under the desk.

Comment: Microsoft Mobile Mouse 4000 here. On/Off switch didn't work but unplugging the dongle for a couple of seconds did the trick. Weird indeed

Comment: I'm truly amazed. Also and still works with a [Logitech MX Master 2S](https://support.logi.com/hc/de/articles/360023459853-MX-MASTER-2S-WIRELESS-MOUSE) in openSUSE Tumbleweed/KDE Plasma 5. @Anwar When looking at the number of different mouses mentioned in the comments here it apparently does.

Answer (score 32):

I wanted to do this too, and I figure I most often want to do it in a web browser (where else do you really mouse-wheel scroll a great deal?)

### For Google Chrome

One can no longer change the scroll amount with command line parameters. However, you can use this add-on extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?utm_source=plus

### For Firefox

1. In the url field, type `about:config`.
2. Search for the following settings and change their values as desired:

   ```
   mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.enabled
   mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.horizontal.factor
   mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.vertical.factor
   ```

Comment: On firefox 17 and up, "mousewheel.withnokey.sysnumlines" and "mousewheel.withnokey.numlines" are both deprecated. The new settings' names is: "mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.enabled", "mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.horizontal.factor" and "mousewheel.system_scroll_override_on_root_content.vertical.factor". You can see it here: https://bitbucket.org/cat_in_136/configuration-mania/issue/101/mousewheelwithnokeynumlines-depracated

Comment: According to a comment below, --scroll-pixels is deprecated and may not be available for chrome anymore. in that case, see this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?utm_source=plus

Comment: For the impatient, regarding the Chromium Smooth Scroller: Settings that worked well for me (trusting you want things faster than default, too): Step Size: 100, Smoothness (forepart): 0, Smoothness: 68, Acc Sensitivity: 115 and (much further down): Bouncy Edge: 0  (irritating gimmick imho)

Comment: Why does that plugin „require“ full access rights to every web page I read?

Comment: I've created a simple chrome extension called Scroll Speed in which you can set the scroll factor.

Can be found here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-speed/mfmhdfkinffhnfhaalnabffcfjgcmdhl

It has much better performance than the "smooth scroll" extensions I've tried to fix this problem.

Answer (score 7):

From triaged [bug #619403](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403) on mouse-wheel acceleration against xorg-server with a link to [this patch](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29905) you can see there is work in progress.

In addition there is a [Wiki on how to configure input devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input) that gives you ideas on what is possible at present:

Use [xinput](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/xinput.1.html) to show setting of your input devices:

`xinput --list` gives you information on your hardware
`xinput query-state "name of device"` lists the current settings (including mouse wheel!)

Only after you know how your mouse is set up you are able to change these setting using `xinput` with the option appropriate for your device.

Comment: how do you apply this patch?

Comment: If not for testing or contributing it is generally not a good idea to patch Xorg server. If you don't know **exactly** what you're doing and something goes wrong you may end up with a non-responsive system.

Answer (score 7):

The option to configure mouse wheel speed in chrome seems to have been removed, however the [Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?hl=en) extension seems to work really well.

Answer (score 5):

This was also annoying me.

This following is one option quoted verbatim from a [comment here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/9200)

> ```
> sudo apt-get install imwheel
> ```
>
> place the following in `~/.imwheelrc`
>
> ```
> "^google-chrome$"
> None, Up, Button4, 2
> None, Down, Button5, 2
> ```
>
> (replace 2 by the number you want to multiply scrolling by)
>
> ```
> $ imwheel
> ```

- I added `imwheel` to my startup applications
- I found the mutliplier `2` to be about right.

**Update:** I found that the following option actually disabled Ctrl+Scroll to zoom, which I quite like.

Comment: Another side-effect is that this affects _all_ mouse wheel events, not just scrolling. E.g. if you ever use the mouse wheel to change tabs this will ruin that functionality :)

Comment: Have a look at this similar post: http://askubuntu.com/a/621140/385212, it demonstrates how to still use Ctrl+Scroll to zoom, etc.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work any longer :(

Comment: This worked in chrome, however any other application it now selects the text rather than scrolling the window :(

Comment: Thanks for the **startup applications** advice. I was digging around „upstart“ which of course is way to early in the process...

Comment: It's matching something in the window title so it needs to be "Google Chrome", not sure if it's case sensitive but I assume it is and also don't limit your window title regex with ^ and $. I think both google-chrome and imwheel need to be restarted every time there's a change in your imwheel config. You can get your window title by using "xwininfo" and clicking on the window. Also I actually found that a factor of 3 is better than 2 but 4 was too fast.

Comment: FWIW this works just fine (Ubuntu 20.04), but it needs to use `imwheel -kill` to enable the changes (just running `imwheel` will have no effect).  I use `.*` as the selector.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

There is a new, great extension for mouse's wheel settings in Chrome. Use it and you can customize your wheel behaviour:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-wheel-smooth-scr/khpcanbeojalbkpgpmjpdkjnkfcgfkhb?utm_source=plus

OLD:

Please note unfortunately --scroll-pixels is deprecated and removed from Chrome and Chromium. This flag has not effect on scroll speed.

More details here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154776