# Ubuntu 14.04 and Dell E6440 - sound and mouse working after suspend/resume

Tags: 14.04, sound, mouse, dell, suspend

I've installed fresh Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Lattitude E6440 and i've encountered two strange issues when doing full system start/restart:
- mouse scroll when full restart is working very fast. One turn of the wheel cause very large change of value (window scroll, sound change etc.) But when i suspend and resume laptop it starts working correctly (one turn of the wheel and small change of value - the same as in previous versions of Ubuntu)
- sound from speakers - the same issue. When full restart the sound does not come from internal laptop speakers. It works though through headphones. After suspend/resume internal speakers starts to work.

What can be a cause of these issues ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

With more digging on the launchpad i've found an answer to the mouse scroll issue. My mouse is Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 1000 and during dual booting (MS Windows -> Ubuntu) the mentioned bug can happen. Solution is to use resetmouse. More detailed answer is on: [Mouse wheel scrolling too fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47100/mouse-wheel-scrolling-too-fast)