# Change mouse wheel scroll speed in Chrome on 12.04 (edit starter bar commandline)

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, mouse-scroll

I want to increase the mouse wheel scroll speed in Google Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've read [How to change my mouse wheel scroll rate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22589/how-can-i-change-the-mouses-wheel-scroll-rate), I'm on Unity though, how can I edit the commandline for the Chrome icon in the starter bar?

Comment: Does the command on the previous question work? like, do you need to just figure out how to edit the shortcut in unity?

Comment: I didn't test it, I just assumed it works. An answer pointing out how to set a system-wide "mouse wheel scrolls by X lines/px/..." option is also very welcome!

Comment: FWIW, here's a relevant search results page. https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=ubuntu+change+mouse+wheel+speed&oq=ubuntu+change+mouse+whee&gs_l=hp.3.0.0j0i30j0i8i30l4j0i22.234.4914.1.6959.25.20.0.5.5.0.127.1468.19j1.20.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.bKuBUI--37U&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.dmg&fp=5cecc5ec14ed7f3d&biw=1366&bih=631

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .desktop files you are looking for are stored in /usr/share/applications/

To change the mouse wheel speed open the .desktop file:

`sudo -i gedit /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

and then go the 'Desktop Entry' section and look for following line (mine is on line 108):

`Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`

and change it to (you can use any value you like instead of 150):

`Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --scroll-pixels=150 %U`

Hint: if you use Chromium instead of Google Chrome, edit the chromium-browser.desktop file ;)

Comment: I was looking for the same thing, and this worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This method appears to be deprecated: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chromium_Tips_and_Tweaks#Scroll_speed_of_mouse_wheel)

Comment: Answer appears outdated (no longer working with current Chrome), see here for a solution → http://askubuntu.com/a/98881/479118