# imwheel destroys back / forth navigation buttons from my mouse

Tags: 13.10, mouse, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I installed `imwheel` correctly with `sudo apt-get install imwheel`. Afterwards I did insert this:

```
".*"
None,       Up,     Up,     10
None,       Down,   Down,   10
```

in my `~/.imwheelrc` file. The scrolling works perfectly now. However the back / forth navigation buttons from my mouse(Logitecg G700) don't work anymore.

If I kill the process with `killall imwheel`, the buttons work.

Do you have any suggestions / ideas how to fix this? I'd like to use `imwheel`.

Answer (score 20):

You can restrict imwheel to only affect the scroll wheel with the `-b` option. See `man imwheel` for more information. Hence, run it with

```
imwheel -b 45
```

Some versions of imwheel (e.g. on Ubuntu 14.04) require a different syntax. If the output of `imwheel --version` is `imwheel 1.0.0pre12 by -=<Long Island Man>=- <jcatki@jcatki.no-ip.org>`, then use the following syntax:

```
imwheel -b "4 5"
```

Comment: -b, --buttons button-spec
The button-spec must be surrounded by quotes.  Each button number must be separated by a space.

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński Is that from the man page? My version doesn't have that text, and this command works perfectly fine. I'm running 1.0.0pre12, which was released 10 years ago.

Comment: Copied from ubuntu man page. Tested.

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński What is the output of `imwheel --version`?

Comment: imwheel 1.0.0pre12 by -=<Long Island Man>=- <jcatki@jcatki.no-ip.org> IMHO this is better, becouse what if your mouse has many buttons with id more than 9 ;)

Comment: @WaldemarWosiński Good point, although in my man, it specifically says it only supports up to id 9. [This](http://pastebin.com/XARUSdtV) is the relevant section of my man page. It even has examples without the quotes and spaces. It's very odd that they differ. Actually, the version of mine has the same number but is slightly different `imwheel 1.0.0pre12 by -=<Long Island Man>=- <jcatki@jonatkins.org>`. I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: So the actual command is `imwheel -b "4 5"` for the lazy.

Comment: Actually, imwheel version `imwheel 1.0.0pre12` requires to be `-b "45"`

Answer (score 6):

I noticed everytime `--kill` or `--buttons` or `-c` is launched, there is a competing instance already running.

Try single line `--kill` and `--buttons`:

```
sudo imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"
```

or

```
sudo imwheel -k -b "4 5"
```

Comment: Brilliant idea to kill the current process