# Chromium browser scrolling slow

Tags: mouse, google-chrome, chromium, scrolling

I just switched from Win7 to Ubuntu (no dual boot) and one thing I kind of  ''miss'' is that I can change the scrolling speed... but I like the scrollspeed in the system itself but not in chromium browser. I don't wan't to use Firefox because my laptop gets too hot using it.

I already tried to use extensions but it doesn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and I have a Dell mouse.

Comment: There was [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/118283/change-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed-in-chrome-on-12-04-edit-starter-bar-commandline) method, but it [might not work](http://askubuntu.com/a/283342/178596).