# How to capture screen in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: screenshot

I'm new to Linux. However I already enjoy what I see. My question is,  how do you make a screen shot when using the Desktop, and what program(s) would I go about using to do it? I would also like to know how to take a screen capture using the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Try in terminal :

```
gnome-screenshot
```

Or in **Dach** search for screen shot and open it .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply press the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> button to take a screenshot. It will be placed into your `Pictures` folder.

This is actually just a hotkey which invokes the command `gnome-screenshot` mentioned by nux.

Comment: but it doesn't work if you have an open menu... the menu closes and you can't actually screenshot the menu

Comment: Hi loonix, curious to see if you could accept an answer for http://askubuntu.com/questions/22589/how-can-i-change-the-mouses-wheel-scroll-rate/101919#101919